# migrate fails due to auth.User

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use rest_framework.authtoken
I'm following this instructions https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

but whenever i try to do python manage.py migrate

```
authtoken.Token.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'auth.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
authtoken.Token.user: (fields.E307) The field authtoken.Token.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'auth.user', but app 'auth' isn't installed.
```

this error happens

I red error message and thought that I need to install "auth"

so I `pip install django-rest-auth`
but it didn't work

and this is my part of my settins.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}
```

it is views.py (i'm working on it so itis not completed)

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@psa()
def exchange_token(request, backend):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        user = request.backend.do_auth(serializer.validated_data['access_token'])

        if user:#drf built in token authentication??
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user) # drf token authentication
            return Response({'token':token.key})
        else:
            return Response(
                {'errors':{'token':'Invalid token'}},
                status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
```

I'm trying to do this to use that "Token.objects~~"
there is no migration file i can fix.. documents just told me to do `python manage.py migrate`

anyone please inform me what is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please firstly run

```
 `python manage.py makemigrations`
```

Comment: I've already did that , 
problem was that I comented out
    'django.contrib.auth',
in settings.py